Need help understanding how to integrate SSO with a third-party widget?
We have a react project that uses AWS Amplify with AWS Cognito as the service provider. We have a custom SAML IdP that we use to authenticate users.
Recently, we have been asked to embed a widget of a third-party application into our application. This application also uses the same IdP to authenticate users.
Currently, when I embed the widget, I get a 400 error code.
This is my first time doing something like this, and this is also a new feature on the third-party application side. So, I just want to make sure that I am doing everything on my side to get this to work.
Am I supposed to be manually storing anything in the browser so that the widget knows the user has already signed in using their credentials in our application? I thought the SSO server would be handling of this.
Any help on this would be appreciated.
Thank you.
